# Palabra reservada "float" en Java

Tags: java

Para que sirve el comando FLOAT en java. Me dejaron un ejercicio donde tengo que capturar matriculas, nombres y las 3 calificaciones de alumnos para despues darle al usuario la opción de consultarlas al ingresar la matricula del alumno y pide usar el comando float para lograr esto. Mi pregunta es para que es y como se usa ? La maestra escrbio esto como ejemplo:

```
float c1[]=new float[20]
float c2[]=new float[20]
float c3[]=new float[20]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`float` es uno de los tipos primitivos de Java. Sirve para almacenar números con punto flotante y tiene una precisión de 32 bits. Para definir e inicializar una variable tipo `float` haces como sigue:

```
float numero = 1.5f; //la F al final es importante, indica que es un float.
System.out.println("Valor de número: " + numero);
```

Lo que tienes en el ejemplo de tu profesora es un arreglo de `float`. Considera que cada elemento de tu arreglo debe tener elementos de tipo `float`. Por continuar el ejemplo de ella:

```
float c1[]=new float[20];
c1[0] = 1.1f;
```

Para más información, puedes revisar la guía oficial de Java: [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score -2):

Las calificaciones por lo general son números con parte entera y parte decimal, por ejemplo, 3,5 o 5,0 o 4,8 y se pueden almacenar en una variable tipo float en java, esta es una forma:

```
float c1=3,5;
float c2=5,0;
float c3=4,8;
```

Tu código presenta corchetes [] o paréntesis cuadrados [] indicando que se almacena más de un valor sobre esas variables, para este caso, 20 valores de tipo float.

```
float c1[]=new float[20];
float c2[]=new float[20];
float c3[]=new float[20];
```

Esto quiere decir que se almacenan 20 números float en la variable c1, 20 números float en la variable c2 y 20 números float en la variable c3.  Ubicar cada calificación en una de las 20 posiciones con los [] las diferencia entre sí y puede indicar lógicamente que estas calificaciones pertenecen a un determinado alumno.  Por ejemplo, el siguiente código muestra las tres calificaciones para el primer alumno:

```
float c1[0]=3,5;
float c2[0]=5,0;
float c3[0]=4,8;
```

Comment: Cuidado. En Java, si declaras `float c1 = 3,5;` **no compila**. Hay dos problemas: 1) La `,` es separador de argumentos, no separador decimal, el separarador de la parte decimal es el punto `.`. 2) Si declaras la variable como `float c1 = 3.5;` tampoco va a compilar. En Java, por defecto, los decimales son de tipo `double` por lo que se debe agregar la letra `f` al final de la declaración literal para indicar que es un número `float`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Puede ser la `f` minúscula o `F` mayúscula, según Java: _A floating-point literal is of type float if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter F or f; otherwise its type is double and it can optionally be suffixed with an ASCII letter D or d ..._ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2